# Check constraints not working on a query/view with join

Tags: sql-server

We have a view described as the following :

```
CREATE view [dbo].[PriceHourlyView]
AS
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2018 WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2017 WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2016 WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2015 WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2014 WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2013 WITH (NOLOCK)
union all
select NodeId, TimeStamp,RtDa,MarketId,Lmp,Mlc,Mcc,Issettledprice,datecreated,IsCalculated from dbo.PriceHourly2012 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Each of the tables has a check constraint as follows for each year except for the current table without year specified :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PriceHourly2017]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_PriceHourly2017_Timestamp] CHECK  (([timestamp]>='2017-01-01' AND [timestamp]<='2017-12-31 23:59'))
```

When this view is queried by itself the check constraints limit the tables being searched. The execution plan looks like this :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM PriceHourlyview
WHERE nodeid = 24511
AND TimeStamp BETWEEN '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-24'
```

[image: Correct check constraints]

Now when I join on this table on the timestamp field the query no longer uses the check constraints and uses every table to check for the data.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM ShapeProfileDetails s WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN PriceHourlyView p WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON s.TimeStamp = p.Timestamp
  AND s.EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-24'
WHERE NodeId = 24512
--AND s.EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-24'
```

[image: Incorrect check constraints]

I know I'm not querying the same field in the joined example and assuming that's the issue but that is the field I need to query for the correct results. I'm wondering if there is anyway to hint or force the query to use the correct check constraints. Or what is the best practice on joining to try and utilize these check constraints.

Comment: you are getting a hash join so it won't be possible to use the check constraints here - the hash join will read all of one side, hash it, then read all of the other side and check if the hashed value exists in the hash table.  What does the plan look like with `LEFT LOOP JOIN`? (I'm not suggesting that you use that hint in practice - just see how the plan looks)

Comment: Looks the same, adds a filter in between the concatenation and each clustered index seek on the table.

Comment: The filter probably has a startup predicate meaning only the relevant table is seeked for each outer row. this might not be a better plan though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as discussed we know that `EffectiveDate` and `TimeStamp` are nearly the same. I would try to do something like this. Technically it's the same query, but we will let know SQL Server that it can use constraints (just subtract and add one day on the edges of `BETWEEN`).

```
SELECT * FROM ShapeProfileDetails s WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN PriceHourlyView p WITH (NOLOCK) 
   ON s.TimeStamp = p.Timestamp 
AND s.EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-24' 
AND s.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2017-05-16' AND '2017-05-25' 
WHERE NodeId = 24512
```

Comment: I've moved around the where/join clauses quite a bit to no avail. Just tried the different join though and that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: That's hard when I cannot query the db myself. Maybe as a last resort just pull the data to a temporary table and then join to ShapeProfileDetails.

Comment: @Kohins Okay, now I see. Why are you using EffectiveDate when your contraints are on TimeStamp? In this case SQL Server won't eliminate other tables. It doesn't know what's in EffectiveDate.

Comment: So the effective date from the other table is to remedy some timezone issues. So what I'm trying to do is select the valid timestamps from the ShapeProfileDetails table then join that to the pricing table to only query the constraint checked tables. I'm not sure if this is possible but that is the idea.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. Is EffectiveDate overlap with TimeStamp? I mean if you want EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-24' then TimeStamp will be in the same or similar range for example BETWEEN '2017-05-16' AND '2017-05-25'?

Comment: Yes they will be. The ShapeProfileDetails holds that information from and varies so that : 
EffectiveDate = '2017-5-17' 
Timestamp = '2017-4-16 23:00:00' or 2017-4-17 00:00:00'

Comment: Okay, so we know that's nearly the same. I would try to do something like this. Technically it's the same query, but we will let know SQL Server that it can use constraints (just subtract and add one day on the edges of BETWEEN). SELECT
  *
FROM ShapeProfileDetails s WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN PriceHourlyView p WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON s.TimeStamp = p.Timestamp
  AND s.EffectiveDate BETWEEN '2017-05-17' AND '2017-05-24'
  AND s.TimeStamp BETWEEN '2017-05-16' AND '2017-05-25'
WHERE NodeId = 24512

Comment: Yeah that will work though I was hoping for a better solution that could use the join logic without having to do the extra date/timestamp distinction on the other table. But maybe that's not possible.

Comment: SQL server is smart, but not that smart ;) I edited my original post to reflect our discussion.